# open a window with external javascripts in Extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, linkedin-api

I would like to open an `Ext.Window` in **ExtJS**, that will open an html file that contains external javascript from LinkedIn.

I have the following code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'About us',
    height: 400,
    width: 800,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        autoLoad: {
            url: 'linkedin_emp1.html',
            scripts: true
        }
    }]
}).show();
```

and the `linkedin_emp1.html` file is:

## List of people

The html file is loaded and I see inside the window just the "List of People" string but not the content that comes from the linkedin javascript.

When I open the same html file from the browser I see everything fine.

It looks like I cannot run an external javascript inside an html.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) element using [`autoEl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-autoEl) config inside of ExtJS.

```
new Ext.Window({
    title : "About us",
    width : 400,
    height: 800,
    layout : 'fit',
    items : [{
        xtype : "component",
        autoEl : {
            tag : "iframe",
            src : "linkedin_emp1.html"
        }
    }]
}).show();
```